# How to follow a question in stack Exchange.

Tags: discussion

There are few questions which are really interesting and I want to follow them. How can I follow a question on stack exchange, so whenever there is comment on that question I can get the notification or mail. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I subscribe for email alert that comes weekly .

http://stackexchange.com/newsletters

Subscribe in above URL for a letter

Also you can subscribe for notification on post of new question every 15 minutes

http://stackexchange.com/filters/72218/my-sites

[image]